# How to display meaningful data from multiple tables (mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query that get the information from these tables. Now by simply using `Select * from Kamp;` I get all the information I want, but as integers as that's what I have selected the columns to be in the `Kamp` Table. But that doesn't give any useful/meaningful information for people who does not know what each integer represents.

What I am looking for is a query that gets the information from each table, connected to the integer displayed in the `Kamp` table so that I can get a complete and meaningful output on the website.

For example:

I want `Deltaker1` and `Deltaker2` (Participant 1 and 2) in `Kamp` to display `Fornavn` + `Etternavn` (Firstname + Lastname) from `Trener`, `Arena` in Kamp to display `Type` + `Adresse` from `Stadio`. I have tried to inner join the tables, but I still end up with the integers.

Hope someone can help me :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Join

```
select k.Deltaker1, k.Deltaker2, 
     t1.Fornavn, t1.Etternavn,  
     t2.Fornavn, t2.Etternavn, 
     s.type, s.Addresse
from Kamp as k 
inner join Stadio as s on s.Stadio_id = k.Arena
inner join Trener as t1  on t1.Trener_id = k.Deltaker1 
inner join Trener as t2 on t2.Trener_id = k.Deltaker2
```

Comment: I still get integers as output: gyazo.com/979433dd2ac989a83d0f1910f0b27420 while what Im trying to get is the information connected to the integers in the respective tables

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8378706a9ecf1d0965a6a9823bbe52a1 still integers as the "5" represents Deltaker1 and "7" represents Deltaker2

Comment: The php error show in your img seem related to some index name / field name not found ... why you are say "still integres as the 5 ..." .. i don't see integer but a php runtime error  .. check your code ..

Comment: I added this query into a fiddle, and it should work just fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37513/1 See for yourself.

Comment: @Qirel,  thanks .. the sqlfddle is clear and work fine .. could be there are some problem in indexing the query result by the OQ author ..

Comment: Perhaps just echoing the wrong column, the first two *are* the IDs, the 3rd, 4th, 5,th and 6th are the ones with actual names. ;-)

Comment: I have leaved this column for permit an correct comprension of the query ..   (I don't know the original code)

Comment: yeah sorry, I believe the error is in how I am trying to echo the array, just mixing up the columns, need to get that sorted as well :p

Comment: Thanks both of you, for your time and help :)